# How to refactor two for loop using map method

Tags: swift, for-loop, refactoring

I'm using swiftyjson library and I wrote this to retrieve urlImage.

```
    for (_, value) in json["assets"] {
        for item in value.arrayValue {
            let urlImage = item["urlImage"].stringValue
        }
    }
```

I want to refactor using flat method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Starting with Swift 4, in most cases, you should use the `Codable` protocol over third party JSON libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
let urlImageArray = json["assets"].map{$1}.map{$0["urlImage"].stringValue}
```

Comment: You know `json["assets"].map{$1}` returns the same as `json["assets"].arrayValue`, yes? The question is long over ofc so this is just for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way using `flatMap` and `map`. Two maps are necessary since it is necessary to iterate over two arrays. `$0` is the standard argument name in a closure if it is not named like `{ arg in`.

```
let urlImages: [String] = jsonObject["assets"].arrayValue.flatMap{
    $0.arrayValue.map{ $0["urlImage"].stringValue }
}
```

And with filtering out empty urlImages:

```
let z: [String] = jsonObject["assets"].flatMap{
    $1.compactMap{
        let urlImage = $1["urlImage"].stringValue
        return urlImage == "" ? nil : urlImage
    }
}

let z2: [String] = jsonObject["assets"].flatMap{
    $1.compactMap{ $1["urlImage"].stringValue }.filter{ $0 != "" }
}
```